# Keycloak performance admin rest api

Tags: performance, keycloak

Keycloak starts to having high latencies when there are 50-100 concurrent users interacting with the Admin REST API. I tested this by using Gatling and run a specific flow which involves calling the Admin REST API. Keycloak uses a H2 database during the performance test. Keycloak is run a docker container within docker for mac.

I tried increasing memory in the JVM flags, but that didn't help.

It shouldn't be a problem to have that many users right ?

Comment: i'm also facing the same problem and using Mysql database.
there are no cpu, memory spikes in either keycloak or mysql